# Как объединить мощность нескольких компьютеров под управлением одной Linux системы?

Tags: linux, сеть, администрирование, железо, ос

В офисе валяется куча ненужных, рабочих системных блоков. Вот я и решил объединить их в единую вычислительную сеть,  а по сути в обычный компьютер управляемый единой ОС, но представляющий собой 3+ системных блока.

Итог: Мне нужно что бы 5+ коробок работала как одна, при этом я не хочу управлять каждым серваком отдельно, моя цель единая машина состоящая физически из нескольких под управлением одной системы. Что она будет делать? Да что угодно, хоть пусть будет web сервером с ip в интернете или просто рабочей станцией Ubuntu или fedora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге я благополучно построил кластер из 10 машин используя операционную систему на ядре Линукс rocks 7

Comment: Конечно это хорошо, что у вас всё получилось. Но вот посмотрите, 5 (пять) учстников потратили время на ответы, пытаясь вам чем-то помочь. В итоге, через 3 года они теперь узнают из вашего полностью безинформативного ответа, что у вас всё получилось, но все их ответы оказались безполегными. То есть, они просто напрасно потеряли время.

Comment: Мой неинформативный ответ тем не менее озвучивает готовую кластерную систему которая полностью решает поставленную задачу из коробки

Comment: Действительно, было бы неплохо озвучить сетап и результат: какие соединения между машинами, как это выглядит для администратора, если есть какие-то объективные цифры (особенно интересует задержка миграции процессов между NUMA-узлами и параметры обращения к нелокальной памяти, конечно), то и их.

Comment: К сожалению цифры не могу предоставить физически. А для администратора система пиедставляесоьой обычный дист линуксу  с графическим окружением из гном из коробки и подключаем годы через pxe загрузку

Comment: Сравните например время компиляции какого-нибудь opensource проекта на с++
Задумался о таком использовании других машин именно для ускорения компиляции

Answer (score 6):

Ответ сводится к тому, что Вам необходимо создать кластер компьютеров под управлением  какой-либо Linux-like OS.

Вот несколько готовых решений:

- [useless link: has been removed].
- [Кластер в домашних условиях](http://linux.yaroslavl.ru/docs/conf/cluster.html).

Для справки:

- [Вики (Кластер)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2)).

Описывать весь процесс в ответе особого смысла нет. Думаю, мой ответ вам полезен.

Comment: Эта статья про "кластер убунту" лишь говорит о написании парралельной программы на языке Fortran (господи прости) с использованием нескольких серверов, а никак не про объединение ресурсов разных серверов в одну linux систему.

Comment: Да я тоже это заметил!

Comment: Да, коллеги. Что то вы слишом много плюсов поставили безполезному ответу (

Comment: @Dillinger è morto , не, но вторая статья то полезна - MOSIX действительно позволяет сделать кластер: в простом виде - перекидывать некоторые процессы на другую машину, и выполнять их там. Конечно до "объединения" мощности далековато - то есть это не совсем эффективно, но работает, факт. Первая конечно не по теме)

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, ага, пофиксил. Спасибо

Answer (score 5):

В таком виде - в котором вы спрашиваете: решения будут неэффективными. Системы из множества компьютеров(серверов) делаются отдельно, под каждую задачу свои, мало того программы - для работы которых и создаётся такая система - тоже пишутся именно под определённые системы серверов.

Называются они "высоконагруженные системы", и их создание/использование - это очень дорогой процесс, который называется "масштабирование". Крупнейшие примеры таких систем - социальные сети: например работу VK обеспечивает 10к машин, но сравнимых по мощности с домашним компьютером(как утверждают владельцы). Да и сам [StackOverflow конечно работает не на одном сервере](https://habr.com/company/ua-hosting/blog/278391/).

Если вам действительно интересно масштабирование: то стоит на крутом уровне освоить системное администрирование, docker, а также почитать лирику на тему хайлода https://ruhighload.com/scale

Comment: Мне нужно что бы 5 коробок работала как одна, при этом я не хочу управлять каждым серваком отдельно, моя цель единая машина состоящая физически из нескольких под управлением одной системы

Comment: @Gybernaty тогда попробуйте mosix - из другого ответа. Или это классическая задача сисадмина - сделать систему серверов: например один сервер выделяется под БД, один под кеш, один под файловое хранилище - а на центральном сервере делаются правильное проксирование портов, алиасы, редиректы.

Answer (score 4):

обычно решения строятся от задачи, а не от платформы

что конкретно вы хотите делать?

из личного опыта -- анализ логов на биллинге, и ретарификация: делал ручным шардингом на уровне приложения (скрипты на Python), на пачке списанных десктопов, аккаунте на конторском IBM eServer, и паре десктопов под windows.

если у вас межсоединения на древнем 100mbit ethernet, а не как минимум 1G (не говоря уж о спецжелезе типа Infiniband) -- дешевле будет пойти в магазин, купить самую поганую материнку и набить ее памятью под завязку, съэкономите на дорогом быстром 1G свитче и энергопотреблении

ваш вариант конфигурации может быть эффективен только в одном случае: все параллельные потоки полностью независиммы, и каждый блок задачи польностью влазит в ОЗУ и ресурсы одного узла, неплохо решаются вычислительные задачи с полным отсутствием зависимостей в архитектуре "одна нода - один расчетный блок"

с другой стороны, в качестве **кластерной рабочей станции** подобная утилизация вполне интересная и имеет право на жизнь, и может оказаться выигрышным вариантом: на рабочей станции активно не более 2-3 тяжелых задач, остальные ресурсы тратятся на хранение гигабайтных вкладок в браузере, текстовые редакторы и редкие пробежки утилит по файловой системе

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_system_image
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_operating_system
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multikernel

Linux реализаций похоже нет:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMosix (R.I.P 2008, kernel 2.4)

так что решение задачи в оригинальной постановке сводится по факту к освоению системного программирования в полном объеме: написать аналог ядра Linux обеспечивающий весь необходимый функционал DOS, адаптировать базовые библиотеки в т.ч. из поставки копиляторов GNU (libc, libatomic, gomp,...) и пересобрать всю систему до состояния, когда сможет работать весь компплект ПО который вы используете

возможно более простым решением может оказаться написание слоя виртуализации: переписать только слой всех системных библиотек, который использует ваше прикладное ПО, с реализацией функционала distributed POSIX поверх обычных дистрибутивов, поставленных на каждый узел, или гипервизоров (желаю много весеслья с исходниками Xen и libgcc/libstdc++ 8-)

с практической точки зрения:

- **ищите задачи с минимальным объемом обмена данными** между потоками, и
- **пишите свое ПО**: смотрите в сторону готовых распределенных платформ для веб/микросервисов, требующие для работы минимальных ресурсов
- **перетаскивайте бизнес-процессы** в вашей конторе **на веб-технологии**, чтобы можно было раздать хилое железо юзерам в качестве терминалов/запускалок браузеров

к сожалению, насколько знаю бесплатных реализаций распределенного Smalltalk не существует, а то бы в первую очередь посоветовал его -- как вариант, искать библиотеки для **программирования на распределенном обмене сообщениями между объектами** для mainstream языков

Comment: Задача проста - управлять несколькими коробками как одной по средствам линукс системы, вот реализация не проста!p.s. Что хочу делать? Да что угодно , то же что и на обычном домашнем компе под управлением убунту например

Comment: http://www.mosix.cs.huji.ac.il/pub/tutorial.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего энергоэффективность (и, возможно, надежность) такой системы будет слишком низка.
Задача кластерных систем - достичь такой вычислительной мощности и отказоустойчивости, которой сложно (или невозможно) достичь средствами одного **современного** сервера. А для утилизации старого железа лучше применить другие способы ;)

Comment: Из корпусов можно создать неплохой сарай или забор. Процессоры пустить на дизайн интерьера туалета.

Comment: Кстати, один из немногих случаев, когда использование устаревшего железа может быть оправдано - это когда тепловыделение реально не минус, а плюс. Например в холодных широтах можно достичь очень неплохого КПД, т.к. энергия, расходуемая на нагрев, не пропадет зря.